# Путь к файлу в однобайтной строке.

Tags: кодировка, c++

Как привести путь файлу из 16 битной строки, в 8 битную так чтоб он корректно обрабатывался даже если в исходной строке есть Юникод.

Comment: Возможно, если все символы из пути к файлу отображаются в целевой кодировке. Если нет -- то нет. Смотрите http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv и далее по ссылкам.

Answer (score 1):

См. [хедер `cwchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cwchar/) и функции в нем, ответственные за перевод строк `wchar_t`  в байтовые строки и обратно. Особенно [wcsrtoms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cwchar/wcsrtombs/).

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то мне кажется, что никак. То есть привести конечно можно, но на этом корректная обработка закончится.

Comment: Да можно, но я не знаю как - в диалог открытия файла возвращает char[], причем если в пути есть киррилица - один кирилический символ становится двумя крякозябрами но все корректно обрабатывается, а вот другие операции с папками дают 16 битные строки, а я уже все в под 8 заточил, брутальное приведение типов срабатываетлиш для путей из латиници.

Comment: @psionic? это у Вас винда?